# Speeded up a slow jQuery Mobile page transition - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery

Background: I have a jQuery mobile app (single .htm, multi-jqm pages) where one of the pages contains a listview with a reasonably large number of list items (300-500 say). I'm testing the boundaries of performance here so currently my custom "paging" will use CSS to hide all but 25 of the items at a time. The app is deployed to devices using PhoneGap.

So, to my question.

I've found that when clicking on an item in the list, navigation to the page the list item links to is extremely sluggish on devices when I use the code below. This handles the click, extracts an id from the list item and stores it, then allows the click to perform the page navigation:

```
    $('#largeListView').on('vclick', 'a[href="#subView"]', function (e) {

        theSubView.setId($(this).data("id"));
    });
```

However, the code below is much quicker. It stores the id also but then prevents the click causing the navigation and manually changes the page instead:

```
    $('#largeListView').on('vclick', 'a[href="#subView"]', function (e) {

        theSubView.setId($(this).data("id"));

        e.preventDefault();
        $.mobile.changePage('#subView');
    });
```

The only downside of the quicker solution (as far as I know) is that the item does not show any UI feedback that a click occurred.

Does anyone know why I get the vast speed improvement here and if there is a way of speeding up option 1 instead?

I don't like circumventing the design in this way and would prefer to use option 1 if I can get good performance.

Thanks!

Chris.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess but maybe this happens due to the fact that the default browser behavior triggers custom events and invokes some scrolling mechanism whereas the $.mobile call avoids this overhead...

I do not think you can improve that so easily but maybe try to use a small delay to perform this asynchronously

```
$('#largeListView').on('vclick', 'a[href="#subView"]', function (e) {
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  setTimeout(function() {
    theSubView.setId(id);
  }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tobias, I tried it just in case but it had no effect. I'll stick with my workaround for now.